# When to use role codes and when to use supertype / subtype

Tags: database-design

What's the best practice to follow when designing a data model when it comes to choosing between using supertype/subtype and role codes?

To be clear, when i say role codes I mean a table design like this:

[image]

Whereas for supertype / subtype I'd do something like this:

[image]

The advantages I see for supertypes / subtypes are that the types aren't mutually exclusive (i.e. food could be both a fruit and a vegetable) and that if you have properties that only apply to one of the types you could either put them in the subtype table, or in another table with a foreign key that points to the subtype table. The disadvantages are that you have to create a table for every sub type.

So does it make more sense to have supertypes / subtypes until you have so many types that it's unwieldy to have a seperate sub type table for every type?

Should you use supertypes / subtypes regardless of how many types you have as long as each type has very different properties?

Or does it make sense to make the decision based on weather your types should be mutually exclusive or not?

I've been struggling with this for a while so any advice from some experienced data modelers on how to make these decisions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database for some discussion about the topic and pros and cons of each solution, as well as related literature. In practice, the decision will depend on the application needs (sometimes non-functional requirements), which may require decisions contradicting ideal designs for optimization purposes- and it may require denormalization and other optimizations- but certainly there is no unique solution.